# Python:How can I find the coordinates of a symbol with number inside (technical drawing)

Tags: python, opencv, numbers, symbols

I am writing a python tool to find specific symbols (e.g. a circle/square with a number inside) on a drawing  pdf/screenshot.png

I know from another data source the specific number(s) that should be inside the circle/square.

Using opencv matchTemplate I can find symbols and its coordinates.

One way would be to created all possible symbols (so circles/squares with number 1 to 1000) and save them. Then use opencv to find it on the drawing since I know the number to be found, and thus the filled symbol.

I am sure that the is a smart way to do this. Can somebody guide me into the right direction.

Note: pdfminer will not work since I will not be able to distinguish between measurement numbers and the text coming from the symbol, but I could be wrong here.

Comment: Can you expand on what you want to actually accomplish? For example, are you looking for a method to find the instances and coordinates of a given polygon given a visual input? Or you have the coordinates and symbols already, so are you looking for something to identify the numbers? In the first case I can't really help because that sounds extremely complicated, but in the second case I can direct you to many examples of the implementation of machine learning to interpret written characters or characters with background 'noise' as would be in an image of a printed page.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to solve a similar problem in a coding assignment. The input is a n low poly art illustration.

[image]

Once you find the location of the UFO's, you need to crop that part and pass it through a classifier to find the number that UFO contains. The classifier is trained on 5000 images.

I am now going to try the matchTemplate method suggested by you to find the co-ordinates of the UFOs.